# Why is obsidian.md not letting me fold lists?

Tags: html, css, themes, obsidian

I would like to be able to fold my lists in Obsidian.md, but it doesn't let me despite toggling the proper flag. I am using the Obsidian markdown editor for taking notes, and I checked the flag for code folding lists by doing `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Fold Indent`.

Here is my screenshot
[image]

I investigated the developer tools and found this line of code

`<div class="cm-fold-indicator" contenteditable="false"> == $0`

And manually toggling the contenteditable tag to "true" caused the expected behavior.

I have closed my app, restarted my computer, but still the issue persists. I am running on Windows 10, Obsidian v1.3.7, and using the Minimal theme. I would appreciate any help with this issue. Thank you in advance!